# Aync/Await in Kendo UI Grid beforeEdit not working as expected

Tags: jquery, async-await, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a combobox in a kendo grid,

```
editor: finishLeftListDropdown
```

That calls this

```
function finishLeftListDropDown(container, options) {
   // this calls to get the combobox for the grid
   itemCellDropDown(container, options, options.model.FinishLeft, "FinishLeft");
}
function itemCellDropDown() {
    .... combobox
}
```

when I click on the cell to edit, I hit the beforeEdit function and I have that set up as async

```
beforeEdit: async function(e) {
    ...Do stuff
    // I get the selected item, then clear out its object and update the combobox with the returned data
    item = e.sender.dataItem(e.sender.select());
    // based on the column that the cell is in, I make a call to the server, so I can use updated data to populate the combobox
    if (colName == "FinishLeft") {
        const lov = await GetAvailableItemLOV("FinishLeft", item.ItemKey);
        item.FinishSideLeftList = [];
        item.FinishSideLeftList = JSON.parse(lov); 
    }
}
```

What happens is that once I go passed the const lov, I immediatley go into the finishLeftListDropDown, then into itemCellDropDown then comes back to item.FinishSideLeftList and by then, as you can see, the combobox didn't get updated with the data from the server and kept its original, and I have to reopen that combobox to see the updated data for it.

My assumption based on what I wrote that it should have waited until the data came back before it continued on.

In short my issue is that I need to populate the combobox with new data when its selected and unsure of why the instead of waiting for the GetAvailableItemLOV to complete.

Comment: What does GetAvailableItemLOV look like?